# execute javascript and .cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a textbox which will receive an input from a scanner.if the textbox is empty and the key is pressed, an error message will appear but if there are any input, it will insert to database.

```
      <asp:Textbox runat ="server" id="Scan" style="width:1200px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000; background-color:white" OnTextChanged="Scan_TextChanged"  Onkeypress=" Keypress()" AutoPostBack="true" " ></asp:Textbox>
```

this is the javascript function.. I don't know how to pass the function to .cs file

```
 $("#Scan").keypress(function(e) {

    var valmsg = $('#Scan').val();

    if (e.which == 13 && valmsg.trim() == "") {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("Scan").value = "There is no desk no entered! Please Scan again.";


    } else if (e.which == 13) {
        //i don't know how to insert the function here
    }
```

this is on the .cs file which i want to execute if there are any input

```
protected void Scan_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strSql;
 string en;
 en = desk;

  string strDeskNo = (Scan.Text);//sepatutnya ada Trim(Scan.Text)
       strSql = "Insert into //sql query
}
```

Please guide me how to do this..
if there are any tutorial that I can learn to understand js better?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE : I use a button to trigger the server method but I still can't enter any value to my database.

```
<asp:button ID="InvisButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="InvisButton_Click" OnClientClick="CallServerMethod()" />
```

```
 protected void InvisButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //query to insert database
        }
```

```
 function CallServerMethod() {
document.getElementById('InvisButton').click();
```

Comment: So you have a web application ? it seems unclear to me what you want to do. An sql query has to be executed on the _server_. Whereas a webpage runs on the _client_. What  is done usually, is that you have an API (in ASP.NET MVC, they are called controller actions) where from your website (in your javascript) you send an HTTP request (a HTTP POST for pushing data, usually). Your API server receives the HTTP request, and insert into the database accordingly.

Comment: $("#Scan") will not be triggered because  <asp:Textbox runat ="server" id="Scan" > textbox will generate different id

Comment: you have to trigger c# method from clientside code

Comment: @GoodSamaritan thank you for replying, I updated my questions, by using button to call the server side. is this way acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, but the question implies lack of **a lot** of knowledge how web pages work, and rather than searching how to do this single thing, I would rather recommend to do some reading in general about ASP.NET, JavaScript, C# and applications architecture. Just google ASP.NET for beginners or something.

Comment: <asp:button ID="InvisButton" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="InvisButton_Click" OnClientClick="CallServerMethod()" /> this button is invisible and onclient click will never happen on this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You are able to call javascript functions from code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "any-string-key", "yourJavaScriptFunction('anyParameter');", true);
```